# Feature request about feature requests

Tags: feature-request

While closing [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/826769/295286) question , I've noticed a few peculiar things:

[image]

- Problem #1: not all software for Ubuntu is hosted on Launchpad, so can we change the text to something like ". . . reported on Launchpad or other software hosting platform that developers of your package use" . The OP can try to argue that their software is not hosted on Launchpad, thus they can't report it, and therefore close reason isn't valid. I know - that's far fetched, but I'm trying to think one step ahead here.  [Oli](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15363/295286) in his answer to a related question also mentions: "... a message that sends everybody to Launchpad isn't appropriate for most projects.
  That's like telling somebody to run ubuntu-bug firefox to submit a feature request. You'd do better to tell them to visit the Firefox support forums (which seems to work as a SE clone)."  So, we don't want to list every single site that provides support for software, but at least we can change it to general term instead of one specific site that excludes all others.
- Problem #2: feature requests are missing. This was [asked before](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/15362/295286) but didn't receive much attention and support. As Takkat said these "...do occur but they are not really many." Bug reports are not very common either, yet we have a specific close reason for them. In addition, I think sending people to the respective software hosting platform that developers use is far better than having an "Closed as off-topic" question here. At least some of the OPs will go to the developer sites and ask for those features, so win-win for both developers and users ( and tangentially - us )

Takkat also mentions:

> "By excluding all feature requests too prominently there may be a risk for a misunderstanding what exactly was meant by a "feature request""

I think it's a pretty clear case when someone comes here and says "Dear developers, please do this and this". When someone asks "Can this be done?" that's another animal.

Comment: Close reasons have a very short character limit, that is probably the reason it is so limited. I highly doubt there is enough space left to add anything else.

Comment: @Seth it's not even possible to reword it ?

Comment: @Serg I agree there may be a risk of problems with this, but if you are suggesting we reword it, perhaps you have a suggestion for what it should say?  Close reasons *are* very short on character limits, so I'm not sure we can truly encompass *all* 'bugs' in a short message.

Comment: @ThomasWard I'll add something into an edit of my question once I am on desktop. I'm on mobile right now

Answer (score 2):

Back before July 2015, we had a [different close reason](https://askubuntu.com/tools/question-close-stats) for bugs:

[image: Bug reports should be submitted via Launchpad so that the developers are made aware of them.]

Honestly, I think something like this would be a better version of the current close reason for bug reports, unreleased software, and feature requests. Perhaps something like:

> **Bug reports**, **feature requests**, and questions about **unreleased software** are off-topic on AskUbuntu. To report a bug or request a feature, [contact the developers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Ideally, the link present in that post would point to a more canonical answer on how to report a bug/request a feature for both Launchpad and non-Launchpad projects. However, that can come whenever needed